# Связь между фабриками в AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, связи

Каким способом лучше наладить связь между фабриками в Angular? Например, в фабрике A я хочу использовать методы фабрики B.

На текущий момент мне известно 2 способа:

1) Сделать ссылку на внедряемую фабрику в $rootScope и использовать ее где угодно

2) Внедрить ссылку на фабрику B при создании фабрики A:

```
$scope.factoryA = new factoryA ({
    injections: {
        factoryB: $scope.factoryB
    }
})
```

Есть ли еще какие-то способы это сделать?

Comment: В принципе основным подходом к этому в Angular считается использование Dependency Injection ([доки](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di))

Comment: DE использую только в том случае, если фабрика B должна создаваться в фабрике A, а если нужны просто методы фабрики B уже созданной в другом месте доступные в фабрике A. Не создавать же ее еще раз.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать паттер "Медиатор" например. Тут собственно вопрос общий, и заключается в том, как в принципе ты бы делал межмодульное взаимодействие.
Пример, медиатора в ангуляре.
http://puigcerber.com/2015/01/22/mediator-pattern-in-angularjs/